# Adsense not working properly in a phonegap+jquerymobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to put an adsense baner in my phonegap app (for iPhone) following the instructions explained in the answer of this post: [jQuery append Google Adsense to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142861/jquery-append-google-adsense-to-div)

But when I run my app it just opens the banner in an external safari window! Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked your question a while ago so this might not matter anymore but I had the same issue in iOS with Adsense in Phonegap. Setting OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES in Cordova.plist solved it for me.