# Is it possible to use any of the Google AdSense version in a jQueryMobile multi-page layout responsive site?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, admob, adsense

I'm trying to integrate any of the Google AdSense versions (AdSense for content, AdSense for mobile, AdMob) for a jQueryMobile **multi-page layout** responsive app that works in mobile browsers as well as desktop browsers.

There are some useful links in Stakoverflow, jQuery Mobile and Google Product forums

- [Bug in Adsense when using jQuery Mobile ajax page transitions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/JkS_HD0JtXY)
- [Is jQuery Mobile's AJAX Navigation System architecturally incompatible with Google Adsense?](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-phonegap-google-adsense)
- [Is it legally possible to monetize a mobile app with jQuery Mobile and Google Adsense?](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-phonegap-google-adsense)
- [Jquery Mobile and Google Adsense – Working!](http://www.adploits.com/2011/10/05/jquery-mobile-and-google-adsense-working/)
- [Load adsense ads through page transition with jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981198/load-adsense-ads-through-page-transition-with-jquery-mobile)
- [Use Google advertising to monetize PhoneGap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485212/use-google-advertising-to-monetize-phonegap-app-built-with-phonegap-build)
- [Adsense for a mobile webapp](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/EK9BYDnxxK4)

But I didn't get a convincing conclusion whether i can legally use any of the adsesne version for jQuery mobile HTML 5 app.

I need to know jQuery mobile mobile website and its PhoneGap build addressses the following issues.

**1.** [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) : Ad placement: *Integrated into a software application (does not apply to AdMob) of any kind, including toolbars.*

**Q**: Can AdSense for content used for PhoneGap HTML5 app?

**2.** [AdSense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) : Product-specific policies: *Publishers may place up to three AdSense for content ad units on each page. Out of those three ad units, no more than one can be size 300x600.*

**Q**: Can AdSense for content used for jQueryMobile **multi-page layout** HTML5 app? In jQM multipage architecture web pages are divs that shows and hides based on URL hash. If I have 10 pages is it possible to show ad in each page

**3.** [Modification of the AdSense ad code](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736) : Techniques to avoid : *Here are some techniques you’ll want to avoid: Hiding ad units at anytime*

**Q**: Can AdSense for content used for jQueryMobile **multi-page layout** HTML5 app addressing the above policy?

**4.** [AdSense for mobile policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en) : *The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled..*

**Q**: Can AdSense for mobile used for PhoneGap HTML5 app?

**5.** [AdMob Mobile Web Sunset](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en) :

**Q**: Can AdMob program used for jquery Mobile HTML5 app (**NOT for PhoneGap**)?

Answer (score 1):

(5) No. Admob is a native mobile advertising SDK. It is not for HTML ad delivery.