# adsense loads in the wrong iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, widget, adsense

I´m having a big big problem with adsense, no matter what I do the adsense result iframe is loading inside other iframe. I´m using WordPress + Bootstrap Framework.

This particular site has two different ads, first use an adserver service which give me his own script, this script is placed in the header.php inside of a `<div id="top-space">` and the adserver handle with the script to show an `<iframe>` and inside that iframe the objet flash of the banner.

The adsense code is in the sidebar and to place it I use a text wodget, put the code there and that´s it.
In 60% of the times the site loads in the correct position each banners, the adserver banners are in the top and adsense ads in the sidebar.

BUT! randomly the adsense iframe is loading inside of the adserver iframe. I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142861/jquery-append-google-adsense-to-div) but don´t work at all.

I´m desesperate because my client is loosing money, the site don´t show the right ads, and some times adsense iframe push adserver ads so the site looks crappy.

Even I try to use adrotate wordpress plugin thinking that help me avoid this bug, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a caching problem. I've noticed in the past, iframes usually don't refresh unless you specifically right-click and refresh each individual one. If you're running any WordPress caching, clear that, then your browser cache, or try an incognito window.